# How to test if a conda environment exists that matches the exact package descriptions of an environment yml file in shell?

Tags: shell, conda

I was to have a line of code at the top of my scripts that checks if a conda environment the current user exists which the contense of exactly matches a corresponding exported environment yml file. I am currently seudo doing this via :

```
test -d ~/miniconda3/envs/antismash_v5 || conda env create -f antismash.yml &&  conda activate antismash_v5 && download-antismash-databases
```

But this only test based on environment name and not actual packages in the environment. Is there a way to do this in shell?

Comment: What exactly is the goal here? E.g., avoiding duplication? Personally, I consider manipulating an end-user's named Conda envs out-of-bounds. If you have software that needs an env, then make the env local to your software and use a `--prefix|-p` not a name. Even if you are making the env again, if the package cache is properly configured, it will mostly be hardlinks (minimal duplication).

Comment: These are just scripts use only within my research group and I just want to ensure they have all the correct packages installed in the correctly named environments for the scripts to execute.